# <li> with a break line add a extra space in IE9

Tags: javascript, html

I have li with display:inline so that it will display in horizontal order.
Now i need to add a break of line so i add something like below,

```
<style>
ul, li {
    display:inline
}
</style>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea<br></li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

I move the br inside li because otherwise it gives a html validation error. But when the br is inside the li it adds a extra space when before the start of the new line. How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes some browser does it with `inline` and `inline-block` elements because being an `inline` element the space between the tags is consider as a part of `HTML` and browser consider it same as we provide space before any inline element

**EXAMPLE**

```
this a a sample text which have <span>inline elements</span> and <a href="#">anchor tags</a>
```

In this code we have space before inline elements and browser keep it. as it is a part of the script ***same is the case with inline li in your case***

*There are many solution for this some of them are listed below*

**Solution 1**

Remove the space in between `li` closing and opening tag

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee
  </li><li>Tea<br>
  </li><li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

**Solution 2**

Apply font size '0' to parent element `UL` and define font size for `li`

```
<style>
ul, li {
    display:inline
}

ul {
     font-size:0;
}
li {
    font-size:1.2em;
}

</style>
```